# Storing items by an ID in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have numerous items that need to be stored and retrieved by their ID. Their IDs, however, do not always start at zero. In fact, they may be much higher, such as 500 or more.

If I store these in an array, so `array[0] -> array[499]` are null and then `array[500] -> array[500+n]` contain the objects, is this going to affect performance? Alternatively, would it be better storing them in `array[0] -> array[n]` and iterating though the list until I find the item with the corresponding ID?

Thanks,
Will

Comment: I would say you can do it as such it best suits your needs

Comment: But if this index is not important for you why you do it so splitting the index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing how you plan on using your array, from the brief description you've given, I would suggest using a [`Dictionary`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) instead.

```
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var someObject:Object {id: 500};
dict[someObject.id] = someObject; // store someObject in key 500

var retrievedObject:Object = dict[500]; // retrieve object from key 500
```

Comment: It's a quiz that's loaded from XML where things refer to one another (like questions to answers) by their ID. It's a little complex, but it basically means I just need to retrieve items now and again from the dictionary by their ID.